# DataTable Load Data via HTML Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatable, datatables

I'm wondering if anyone can explain the best way to load data into a DataTable using an HTML button.

I'll have a drop down menu with each menu item corresponding to a SQL query. I want to have an HTML button that the user clicks on to update the DataTable with the selected query from the drop down menu.

Please point me in the right direction.

**Update** - Here's what I've got so far:

```
<?
//Connect to database and return $results
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Run Reports</title>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>        
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"/>
        <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.4.0/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.4.0/js/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.4.0/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.4.0/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.4.0/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css"/>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/0.1.27/build/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/0.1.27/build/vfs_fonts.js"></script>

        <style>
            div.container {
                margin: auto;
                width: 80%;
            }
            div.dt-buttons{
                margin-left: 350px;
                margin-top: 10px;
            }
        </style>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
        <table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Column 1</th>
                    <th>Column 2</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <?
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
              echo '
              <tr>
                <td>'.$row["ID"].'</td>
                <td>'.$row["user_login"].'</td>
              </tr>
              ';
            }
            ?>

        </table>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#example').DataTable( {
                dom: 'lfrtipB',
                buttons: [
                    'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
                ]
            } );
        } );
        </script>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That will have to be done using [DataTable's `ajax()`](https://datatables.net/manual/ajax) call. The result from your SQL query will have to be in `json` structure too.

Comment: Have you made a start on it at all? Anything we can use to base our answers on?

Comment: Part of the problem is that you're using datatables on client-side data, ie you're creating the table in HTML and then applying the datatables plugin. For what you need, you should update the code to use the datatables API to load the data via ajax, [here's a tutorial](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html)

Comment: I'm going to use the DataTables "Server-side processing" to load the table data. I'll create JSON data from the PHP query code for Ajax. I'll use a PHP switch statement to determine which HTML / JQuery snippet to use based on the drop down menu selection.  Does that make sense?